# How to perform Html.Action on javascript event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a div within a cshtml file that shows the view from another action, as follows:

```
<div id="tabs-1ua">
  @Html.Action("Index", "Admin")
</div>
```

This loads fine on initial page load. In a separate js file, I have an event catcher for the div as follows:

```
$("a[href='#tabs-1ua']").click(function (event, ui) {

    $("#tabs-1ua").val("@Html.Action('Index', 'Admin')");

});
```

As can be seen above, the val parameter is the same Razor code that appears in the original div. However, this doesn't get me the desired outcome of the action being performed each time that div event is activated. What is the correct way to activate the razor code each time the event occurs? I made sure the event is captured by testing with alerts, so that's not the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the outcome?  what is currently happening?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid currently, the div still shows the same content as from the initial load, even though I can confirm that the content should have changed.

Comment: Have you debugged? Is the action being hit with a breakpoint?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I just debugged and saw the action gets hit only on the initial load of the page, but not when the click event occurs.

Comment: Okay, I doubt it would have been hit, I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with this.. `.val()` is primarily used to get values of form elements, not call out to an action in the controller.. if you want to do that, then I would look into using **ajax**

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I am trying to load the action again in the div each time it is clicked, just as it is when the page is loaded. Basically I am looking for a way to set the content of the div each time it is clicked on, with the content being the result of the action.

Comment: Okay, then you definitely need to look into [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  That is your best bet to do calls to the server (controller) with JavaScript

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid thanks for pointing towards ajax, while I was researching it got answered with ajax below.

Comment: glad I could be of assistance & that you got what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to load the desired content asynchronously using ajax, doing something like this:

```
$("a[href='#tabs-1ua']").click(function (event, ui) {

   $.ajax({
       url: "/Admin/Index",
       data: {}
   }).done(function (htmlResponse) {
       $("#tabs-1ua").html(htmlResponse)
   });
});
```

This loads the result of the action inside the div with id=tabs-1ua.

Maybe this is a simpler approach, let me know if i can be of further help

Comment: You´re welome, glad it helped, happy coding!